# How to properly use flex to align two components side by side (Material UI + ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am attempting to achieve side by side components of two cards ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card )and did so successfully. But when I expand the card, the following occurs:

[image]

Card 1 is never manually clicked to be expanded, yet when Card 2 is expanded, Card 1 itself expands to the size of the expanded Card 2 even though Card 1 has never been clicked on for expansion. I looked around but can't seem to find the solution for the issue. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Following is the snippet code for it:

```
       <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
          <Card style={{ marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30, flex:1}}>
            <CardHeader
              title="Card 1"
              subtitle="Updated 5/11"
              actAsExpander={true}
              showExpandableButton={true}
            />
            <CardMedia 
              expandable={true} 
            >
              <img src="card1.PNG" />
            </CardMedia>

            <CardText expandable={true}>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
              Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
              Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
            </CardText>
            <CardActions expandable={true}>
              <FlatButton label="Action1" />
              <FlatButton label="Action2" />
            </CardActions>
          </Card>

        &nbsp;

          <Card style={{ marginRight: 30, flex:1}}>
            <CardHeader
              title="Card 2"
              subtitle="Updated 5/11"
              actAsExpander={true}
              showExpandableButton={true}
            />
            <CardMedia 
              expandable={true}
            >
              <img src="card2.PNG" />
            </CardMedia>
            <CardText expandable={true}>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Donec mattis pretium massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi.
              Donec vulputate interdum sollicitudin. Nunc lacinia auctor quam sed pellentesque.
              Aliquam dui mauris, mattis quis lacus id, pellentesque lobortis odio.
            </CardText>
            <CardActions expandable={true}>
              <FlatButton label="Action1" />
              <FlatButton label="Action2" />
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you can see in the [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property) the initial value for the `align-items` property is **stretch**, and that's what causing the first card to expand when the second is expanded..
In order to fix it you can just change the value of the `align-items` property in your parent div like `display: 'flex', align-items: 'flex-start'`